# Within a range that occurs multiple times: move lines containing pattern to the line before the end, and decorate them

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

In my case I need to edit a big bunch of CMakeLists.txt at once - but I think this problem can be generalized. The questions are:

1. Which tool is better for the job?
2. How would I achieve the desired output?

`[Optional:]`

3. Is there a way to empty/erase the hold space in sed?
4. Is there a way to prepend or append lines in the hold space?

Both target_include_directories calls may or may not have identical arguments.

## Problem Statement:

Within the range of `target_include_directories(` and the first `)` collect all the lines containing `windows` indent them (by 4 spaces) and put them before the `)`.

Now insert `$<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:` with correct indentation before the block of lines containing `windows` (inside the range defined above) and append one line containing an indented `>` after the block of lines containing `windows`.

Also make sure the last line containing arguments of each block has no semicolon and all the others do.

#### Research done so far:

The following line collects the lines containing windows and puts them to the right place, but without indentation and without the decoration.

```bsh
sed ':j;/^$/h;/target_include_directories(/,/)/{/windows/{H;d};/)/{H;x;D;G;bj}}' CMakeLists.txt
```

### Sample data:

```
...
##############
# Unique Big Block
##############
if(some_condition)
    target_include_directories(foo Public
        arg0floor;
        arg1windowsred;
        arg2chairs;
        arg3bluewindows;
        arg4tables;
        ...
        argnwalls
    )
elseif(some_other_condition)
    target_include_directories(foo Public
        arg0yeast;
        arg1windowsbroken;
        arg2barley;
        arg3wavywindows;
        arg4water;
        ...
        argnsugar
    )
endif()
##############
# Other Unique Big Block
##############
...
```

### Expected output:

```
...
##############
# Unique Big Block
##############
if(some_condition)
    target_include_directories(foo Public
        arg0floor;
        arg2chairs;
        arg4tables;
        ...
        argnwalls
        $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:
            arg1windowsred;
            arg3bluewindows;
            ...
            argkwindowsblack
        >
    )
elseif(some_other_condition)
    target_include_directories(foo Public
        arg0yeast;
        arg2barley;
        arg4water;
        ...
        argnsugar
        $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:
            arg1windowsbroken;
            arg3wavywindows;
            ...
            argkmilkywindows
        >
    )
endif()
##############
# Other Unique Big Block
##############
...
```

Comment: `awk` or `perl` are better suited than `sed`

Comment: Thank you, I'll search for a solution with `awk` then. Could you point out some names of the _mechanisms_ in `awk` I might need for this task?

Comment: About your optional question 3: Actually, you don't want to empty the hold space, but preload it on each block start: `/target_include_directories(.*/{h;s//    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:/;x;}`. Additionally, you seldom need to loop in `sed`, let `sed` loop for you: `sed '/target_include_directories(.*/{h;s//    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:/;x;};//,/)/{/windows/{s/^/    /;H;d;};/)/{H;x;};}'`. So you were already pretty close. But this comment is just meant for improving your `sed` understanding. I'd use Python for such a task.

Comment: Oh my, i just learned `The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match` @Philippos ... I will meditate over this one-line of beauty. I extended it to my needs a bit `sed '/target_include_directories(.*/{h;s//    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:/;x;};//,/)/{/windows/{s/^/    /;H;d;};/)/{s/^\(\s*\))/\1\1>\n\1)/;H;x;};}'`. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's the idea here: To learn from each other. (-: And I just learned that the multiple spaces inside backticks in my comment were eaten by the editor. Both replacements were supposed to add the indention spaces.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the same with my adjustment - but I am lucky to understand enough of the command to fix that :)  ... By the way I used your answer in my script and will use the explanation of Stephen to understand awk better. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I agree with [Bodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/330217/bodo), AWK or Perl are better suited. I’d use AWK here, it’s sufficient for the job.
2. Here are the steps involved. AWK is a record-based pattern-matching language; by default, a record is a line. So in this instance, I’d write a program which would

   1. look for `target_include_directories`, and note that we’re now in an include block;
   2. when in an include block, match lines containing “windows”, and store them in an array instead of outputting them; other lines are output as-is;
   3. when in an include block, look for the closing parenthesis; when found, output the stored lines, with the platform prefix.

   There’s some extra handling involved to deal with the end-of-line semi-colon; one way to deal with that would be to store the include lines without leading spaces and trailing semi-colons, and output them decorated as appropriate for the context.

   One implementation is as follows:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/gawk -f

   # Note the start of a block, clear the memorised includes,
   # print the current line and skip to the next one
   /target_include_directories/ {
       in_include_block = 1
       delete includes
       print
       next
   }

   # In a block, if we match "windows", memorise the value without its semi-colon
   in_include_block && /windows/ {
       includes[length(includes)] = gensub(";", "", "g", $1)
   }

   # In an include block, when we reach the end, output the memorised includes
   in_include_block && /)/ {
       if (length(includes) > 0) {
           printf "        $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:"
           for (i = 0; i < length(includes); i++) {
               if (i > 0) {
                   printf ";"
               }
               printf "\n            %s", includes[i]
           }
           print "\n        >"
       }
       in_include_block = 0
   }

   # In an include block, if we don't match, print the line
   in_include_block && !/windows/

   # Outside include blocks, print
   !in_include_block
   ```

Comment: I must admit, that my experience with awk is extremely limited (except of a one-liner I pinned to my workplaces cardboard-wall `!x[$0]++`). So I assume with denoting that we are in an include block you mean something like  (in_include_block=1) right? Then something like if (in_include_block == 1) {/windows/ ...} Well I am already stuck. I especially don't seem to understand how to store things to an array and then print them just before /\)/ occurs...

Comment: See the example implementation above.